# What's the best way to look for a text fragment (selection in text) on an arraylist of fragments that compose that text?

Tags: java, android, string, search, arraylist

I'm having troubles looking for text coincidences on arraylist. I have this structure:

```java
public class Fragment {
    private int id;
    private Date date;
    private String text;
    private Profile profile;
}
```

I have and activity that gets from API the list of fragments and put them on an `ArrayList<Fragment>`. and it also creates a TextView with all the fragments. Then I have a custom `ActionMode.Callback` for showing context menu options like "Search".

When clicking "Search" menu option, I want to search in that fragment list for coincidences with the selected text, but the text could not be a fully coincident fragment. For example, having this fragments on the list:

```java
fragments.get(0).getText() //returns "Hi"
fragments.get(1).getText() //returns ", Mi name is Peter"
fragments.get(2).getText() //returns ", how are you?"
```

And the text selected is "is peter, how are"

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could do it. It basically created a boundary where the match occurs based on the full text and finds the fragments that this boundary overlaps with. I added some comments for clarification.

```
//Set up an example arraylist
ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
fragments.add(new Fragment("Hi"));
fragments.add(new Fragment(", My name is Peter"));
fragments.add(new Fragment(", how are you?"));

//Create a full string of all fragments together
String total = fragments.stream().map(Fragment::getText).collect(Collectors.joining());
String toMatch = "Peter, how";

//Search and check for a match in the full string, store the index where the match starts
int matchIndex = total.indexOf(toMatch);
if (matchIndex >= 0) {
    //Store the index where the match ends
    int maxMatchIndex = matchIndex + toMatch.length();
    ArrayList<Fragment> overlap = new ArrayList<>();
    //Keep track of the current character index we're at compared to the full string
    int processed = 0;
    for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
        //Add any fragments that lie between the start and end index of the match to the overlap arraylist
        if(processed + fragment.getText().length() >= matchIndex && processed < maxMatchIndex) {
            overlap.add(fragment);
        }
        //Add the length of the processed fragment to update the "full string index" for the next check
        processed += fragment.getText().length();
    }

    //Do something with the match, here we just print the text
    for (Fragment l : overlap) {
        System.out.println("Fragment match: " + l.getText());
        //Prints:
        //  Fragment match: , My name is Peter
        //  Fragment match: , how are you?
    }
}
```

Note that I created a basic constructor to insert text and a getter to compare the text.

Comment: And what about if the selected string to search for is: "Peter, how are"?

Comment: @IanOrtega In that case you would probably have to stitch together all the fragments, check for the index where the match occurs and resolve all the fragments that it overlaps from there. If you want I can write up an example

Comment: I was thinking on creating a `HashMap<String, Fragment>` where the String is composed like `startIndex+"-"+endIndex` with the fragment start index on the text, the fragment end index on the text and the fragment itself, then getting the start and end indexes of selected text and searching on the map...

Comment: @IanOrtega I have updated my answer to an example that should reflect what you were asking. It functions pretty similarly to what your idea was :)

Comment: No problem, it was an interesting problem to look at really quick. Good luck man!